# formnovalidate doesn't work with IE10 and type=image

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

i'm trying to avoid the validation in a input of type image but with IE10 seems that doesn't work if the input is a image type.

Someone know a solution to avoid the validation or similar? Thanks in advance.

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="demo.asp" method="post">
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="userid" required>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="submit" formnovalidate  value="submit as admin">
    <input type="image" formnovalidate value="no validation">    
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an older question but you could add the following function:

```
handleSubmit(element) {
   var form = document.forms[0] ;
   form.noValidate = !!element.formnovalidate ;
   return true;
}
```

then attach the function to the submit buttons with `handleSubmit(this)`